# Optimized search for different fields in an object

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures

Let's say that I have a structure like this:

```
struct Pack
{
    unsigned int id;
    string name;
    string surname;
    string username;
    string address;
};
```

If I want to search for a given "username" in a collection of this type of objects I can store them
in a std::map with the 'username' as a key and the proper pack object as value.

But what if I want to also search for a given ID ?

A solution that I came with to this problem was to have the data in another data structure (like a linked list) and
2 separated std::maps. First map will have the "username" key and the second the "id" key. As value they both will have a pointer to the proper Pack object.

Also, I forgot to mention one important thing. If I also want to delete an object I will also need to delete the entries from the 2 std::maps. And the deletion procedure will get 'heavier' if I want to increase the number of std::maps (search for given name, surname etc).

Are there better solutions to this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: If performance is important than don't use linked list.. its a complicated structure. You should use arrays-structure. take a look at [Packed Structure](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/)

Comment: @Mike Your solution is a good one. Each `map` is similar to a database index, and the `list` is similar to a database table. They're just in-memory.

Comment: @DOOM a linked list is appropriate here. If new elements can be added after the `map`s have been created, an array would invalidate the old pointers in the `map`s. The pointers in a linked list would remain valid.

Comment: Depending on the objects stored, vector is often more efficient than map since it is cache friendly. If performance is really a concern, you should already be setup for profiling and switching container is not that hard to do in order to test. Make it run, then make it run faster if needed.

Comment: @Alex Yes you are right .. I miss the delete part !! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have efficient lookup on different keys, there's really no way to get around having a maps for each - there may be libraries that abstract this for you, but something similar will still be happening behind the scenes.

But you needn't have a linked-list at all. You can have both (or all) maps have pointers directly to the `Pack` objects. There's no need to have these `Pack` objects reside in a secondary structure.

Also, you could use an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead of a `map` to get expected O(1) operation performance, rather than O(log n).